# No data returned though I'm in Deezer country

Tags: deezer

I'm building a wepp app from Sweden. And I want to access the Deezer api to search for music. I have registered an app and I am a premium user.

But still when I run my queries from my server on GoDaddy it doesn't work. But the server in Sweden works with the same code.

Is there any way I could get the data on the Godaddy server or do I need to move everything to the server in Sweden?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is located in the US or another country where Deezer's not live yet, you won't get results.

You can work around that issue by passing an access_token parameter with the request. If the access_token is associated with a Premium+ user who registered in a Deezer live country (e.g. Italy for example), the request will take the user country associated with the token into account. Therefore, it will return results.
That above workaround isn't working for free users.